# $f$ is defined and positive in $[0,1]$ for $1>a>0 \implies \inf f((a,1])>0$ if $f$ continuous on the right at $x=0$ proof that $\inf f([0,1])>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

I have this problem :

$f$ is defined and positive in $[0,1]$  for $1>a>0 \implies \inf f((a,1])>0$.
if $f$ continuous on the right at $x=0$ proof that $\inf f([0,1])>0$

**My proof**

Since $f$ is continous on the right at $x=0$ we know that : $$\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)=f(0)$$

I thought to assume that $\inf f([0,1])\leq 0$, and using the limit inorder to get a contradiction but haven't managed to get there, Any ideas how to "move on" from this point?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands the result is not correct. Take, for example, $f(x)=x,\ x\in[0,1]$. Then $f$ is positive, continuous everywhere, $\inf f((a,1])=a>0$ for every $a\in(0,1]$ and $\inf f([0,1])=0$.

One way to correct it is to assume that $f(0)>0$. I will now prove the statement with this assumption. Since $f\ge 0$ we must have that $\inf f([0,1])\ge 0$. Suppose that $\inf f([0,1])=0$. Then, for every $a\in(0,1]$, it holds that $\inf f([0,a])=0$ since $0=\inf f([0,1])=\min\{\inf f([0,a]),\inf f((a,1])\}$ and $\inf f((a,1])>0$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary, but fixed. Then, by the definition of the infimum, for every $n\ge 1$ one can find $x_n\in[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ such that $f(x_n)<\epsilon$ ($\inf f([0,\frac{1}{n}])=0$). We pass to the limit ($n\to\infty$) and use the continuity of $f$ in $0$ to deduce that $f(0)\le\epsilon$. $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, so this forces $f(0)=0$, which is a contradiction. It follows that $\inf f([0,1])>0$, as required.